# value emitted doesn't bubble up with EventEmitter

Tags: angular

I have the error message below when I try to pass the method `onDeleteComment` to another component.

> messageId = [object Object]
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

**messages-item.component.ts**

```
onDeleteComment(messageId: string, comment: Comment) {
  /* For debugging purpose only x*/
  console.log('messageId = ' + messageId);
  console.log('comment.text = ' + comment.text);

  //this.commentService.deleteMessageComment(messageId, comment);
}
```

**messages-item.component.html**

```
<div class="component-container" *ngIf="message$ | async as message; else loading">

  /* ... */

  <div *ngFor="let comment of message.comments">
    <app-comments-item
      [commentId]="comment"
      (deleteComment)="onDeleteComment($event)"
      [sourceId]="message._id">
    </app-comments-item>
  </div>

</div>
```

**comments-item.component.ts**

```
export class CommentsItemComponent implements OnInit {
  comment$: Observable<Comment>;
  @Input() commentId: string;
  @Output() deleteComment = new EventEmitter<{sourceId: string, comment: Comment}>();
  @Input() sourceId: string;
 
  /* ... */

}
```

**comments-item.component.html**

```
<div class="component-container" *ngIf="comment$ | async as comment; else loading">
  <div class="header-container">

    /* ... */

    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="deleteComment.emit({sourceId: sourceId, comment: comment})">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

 /* ... */

</div>
```

How to bubble up the comment to my messages-item component?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What;s being logged for messageId? I imagine it's actually an object with both your sourceId and comment

Comment: messageId = [object Object] for the line `console.log('messageId = ' + messageId);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $event will be an object with two properties.

Change your function like so:

```
onDeleteComment(event: {sourceId: string, comment: Comment}) {
  /* For debugging purpose only x*/
  console.log('messageId = ', event.sourceId);
  console.log('comment.text = ', event.comment.text);

  //this.commentService.deleteMessageComment(messageId, comment);
}
```